# Using a KillSwitch in an akka http streaming request

Tags: http, akka, akka-stream

I'm using Akka's HTTP client to make a connection to an infinitely streaming HTTP endpoint. I am having difficulty getting the client to close the upstream to the HTTP server.

Here's my code (`StreamRequest().stream` returns a `Source[T, Any]`. It's generated by `Http().outgoingConnectionHttps` and then a `Flow[HttpResponse, T, NotUsed]` to convert `HttpResponse` to a stream of `T`):

```
(killSwitch, tFuture) = StreamRequest()
  .stream
  .takeWithin(timeToStreamFor)
  .take(toPull)
  .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
  .toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.both)
  .run()
```

Then I have

```
tFuture.onComplete { _ =>
  info(s"Shutting down the connection")
  killSwitch.shutdown()
}
```

When I run the code I see the 'Shutting down the connection' log message but the server tells me that I'm still connected. It disconnects only when the JVM exits.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what I should be doing differently here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you should invoke `Http().shutdownAllConnectionPools()` when `tFuture` completes. The pool does not close connections because they can be reused by the different stream materialisations, so when the stream completes it does not close the pool. The shut connection you seen in the log can be because the idle timeout has triggered for one of the connections.